# Prove that dim$(N(A^{2}))=$ dim$(N(A)) +$ dim$(N(A) \cap C(A))$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that dim$(N(A^{2}))=$ dim$(N(A)) +$ dim$(N(A) \cap C(A))$

Where $N$ denotes the null space and $C$ denotes the column space.

My attempt:
Since $Ax=0$ implies $A^{2}x = 0$

$N(A) \subset N(A^{2})$

So dim$(N(A)) ≤$ dim$N(A^{2})$

In $N(A) \cap C(A)$, we have those vectors which are in the null space of $A^{2}$.
But how can I use this information for my proof?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $M$ be a subspace such that $N(A^2)=N(A) \oplus M$. Show that $N(A) \cap C(A)=A(M)$, and then that $\dim(N(A) \cap C(A))=\dim(M)$.

Comment: What is $A(M)$ here$?$

Comment: @Mathaddict The image of $M$ by $A$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Look at the restriction of the linear map $A$ to $N(A^2)$.

With the domain so restricted, what are the kernel and the image of this map? In fact, can you prove that its kernel is $N(A)$ and its image is $N(A)\cap C(A)$?

Now apply the rank/nullity theorem.